# Question with creating/declaring data types(int,string,streamreader)

Tags: c#

Ok so i'm halfway into the semester in a C# coding class and I just have a simple question.

When Im reading others code I see people do something like this:

```
string exampleString = new string();

StreamReader exampleSr = new StreamReader();

Int exampleInt = new int();

char a = new Char();
```

I have a few questions:
For like the String one, wouldn't it be the same if I just did 
`string exampleString = " ";`?

What do people use these for?
And also what goes inside the parenthesis?

Just a few simple questions, im not sure what to search up to my find the answer to my questions so im asking here, Thanks!

Comment: Before starting c#, first go through OOPS concepts.

Comment: Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2) about the string class in C#

Comment: You need to get familiar with [Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

Comment: If you halfway through the semester, then surely you are familiar with constructors?

Comment: Also, if you see someone using one of the constructors you mentioned besides `StreamReader exampleSr = new StreamReader()'`, you are allowed to yell at them :)

Comment: I have voted to close this question.  Although you haven't explicitly asked for a tutorial, that's really what you need here.  There are many resources online that will explain basic C# concepts like this.

Comment: Note that `" "` (a string containing a space) is not the same as an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of the string, `string a = "";` is not the same as `string b = new string();`.
Why:
a is now set to literally "", that means an empty string.
trying to define b in the way shown above will result in an error, because the constructor of `string` is not defined for 0 arguments.
you can declare a cariable like this, too:
`string c;`
this will result in an empty variable with no value in it (yet).
you'll have to assign it a value before you can use it, though (otherwise you'll get an error).

I'm not sure if i gave you a useful answer, so please ask me if you have any further questions.

Comment: Ok so say I do StreamReader sr = new Streamreader("File.txt"); Does that assign the text in the text file to the streamreader variable "sr"? and if so could I assign it to a string (Ex: string c;  c = sr.Text) or would that not work?

Comment: @IssaHachem well, `sr = new StreamReader("File.txt");` would create a new StreamReader object for the file "File.txt" inside your current directory. You could then read the contents of that file into a string by using `string content = sr.ReadToEnd();`. Whenever you're working with an unfamiliar data type, look up its functions and properties online. This usually helps a lot. For the StreamReader class check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader

Comment: Alright will do, I understand all this a lot better now. Many thanks!

Comment: no problem. Happy I could help!